# Amazon Cloud Services to make configuration and scaling easier

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud

I am looking for a way to make the switch to Amazon EC2, but would prefer to go through a service such as scalarium.  They are supposed to make load balancing and configuration extremely easy.

My question is, do any of you use this and perhaps there are other better alternatives out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked into Amazon's own solution to load-balancing? http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

Comment: Ive been checking that out as well, but am unsure as to what route I am going to take. . . I'm not quite sure why I might choose one over the other at this point....

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at scalr: http://scalr.net/ Really depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Following Zen answers, if you want to understand better how [Scalr](http://scalr.net) manages Amazon Load Balancers, you can read our [wiki](http://wiki.scalr.net/Tutorials/Load_Balancing) (Disclaimer: I work at Scalr). Basically, Sclar completely automates the auto-scaling process depending on any parameters (CPU, Ram...). Scalr is open-source and is available as a hosted software.
I'm not sure what Scalarium exactly does, but they probably automate this in the same way.